# Converting a definition to a limit form

Tags: probability, limits, random-variables, definition

Set $S$ is the set of infinite sequences (each sequence of the form: $a_1,a_2,...$) where each term $a_i\in A$. Let $u_a^{T_0}$ represents number of times $a\in A$ occurs before index ${T_0}$ in a particular sequence. (The probability with which a particular $a$ occurs at any index is $p_a<1$) 
The statement is: 
"For every $u\geq0$ and $\delta>0,$ there exists $T_0\geq u$ such that
$$P(\forall a \in A: u_a^{T_0}>u)\geq 1-\delta$$
where $P(.)$ represents the **sum of** the probabilities of the event (inside the brackets) over all sequences." 
Note that this is just a statement, which may or may not be true. 
So is there any way this could be written as a limit of something? There seems to be a resemblance between the definition of limit to $\infty$ and this, but I cannot just work out the exact form.

Comment: If you let me have a look at the document from where you're reading this up (or class notes , if you took this down during a class), I can help. I've seen this before, but the notation is unfamiliar.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea at all what you said or want to know

Comment: @mathworker21, please see the edits. I've reframed the problem in terms of a more general setting.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, I am afraid I don't have the right to do that, but I've reframed the question details, please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will have a look and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

I read it as

$\quad$ "For each $u$ fixed, the probability of the event

$\quad$(each $a \in A$ appears at least $u$ times in $a_1,\ldots,a_{T_0}$)

$\quad$ tends to $1$ as $T_0\to ∞$."

Another way of writing this would be: $\forall u > 0$,

$$\mathbb P\left(\min_{a \in A}\#\{n \leq T_0\,:\, a_n = a\}\geq u\right) \to 1 \qquad \text{as}\qquad T_0 \to ∞.$$

---

A weaker statement than this is the following:

- "With probability 1, every element $a \in A$ appears infinitely many times in $(a_n)_{n=1}^∞$":

it is weaker than your statement because your's has a kind of "uniformity" built in — it is equivalent to the $p_a$ being uniformly bounded away from 0 (i.e. $\inf_{a\in A}p_a > 0$). A counterexample would be with any infinite $A$, e.g.

$$A = \mathbb N = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}, \qquad p_a = 2^{-a}:$$

even though every symbol will almost-surely appear infinitely often, there's no way that it can satisfy your statement. Same goes for $A$ finite with some of the $p_a$ equal to zero.

Otherwise, it should hold just fine! (Assuming the $p_a$ applies to all $n$ independently.) You may want to look up [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Properties_and_examples) and the proof that a number is normal with probability one (using the [Borel-Cantelli Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma)).
It may yield good intuition why the above is true in this case.

Comment: Is it correct to say $T_0\to \infty$? Since all that my statement comments on is about the existence of a satisfying $T_0$ for every $u\geq0$.

Comment: Certainly. Perhaps I should have used $t$ instead of $T_0$ there. $T_0$ really acts as the constant you provide in the proof of convergence. I.e.:
$$\; $$
Fix $u$. Let $e(t)$ denote the event that each term in $a$ appears at least $u$ times in the first $t$ terms, and suppose you are given $\delta>0$ and have found a $T_0$ which implies $$\mathbb P (e(T_0)) > 1 - \delta.$$ Then for $t \geq T_0$, $e(T_0)\implies e(t)$ so $$\mathbb P (e(t)) \geq \mathbb P (e(T_0)) > 1 - \delta.$$
That is, for all $t \geq T_0$, $\mathbb P (e(t)) \in (1 - \delta,1]$; and $\delta$ is as small as you like.